# Skipping autosys job execution

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys, jil

I wanted to start a job in certain time range. If the starting conditions are not met before the specified time, the job should skip the execution for that day & should run asusual for the next day. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use time window:

```
insert_job: job_name
machine: machine
owner: owner@us
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
exclude_calendar: s_holidays
start_times: "20:00"
run_window: "20:00-07:00"
```

Comment: I tried using it but it didn't worked. Job set up is in such a way that box starts at scheduled time(no starting conditions to it) &the core job inside it has a global variable set as starting condition. Requirement here is that if the global variable is unset(for supporting any RFC) then the job execution shouldn't take place after certain time range.
When used run_window attribute, the core job is getting triggered if I release the global variable after the time range is crossed which doesn't satisfy my requirement.